# writing good abstract classes in java

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have the following need and please help me to write good and abstract class.

1. Different types of operations is needed based on the type

I have a abstract class,

```
abstract public class FileHelper{

    //Template method
    //This method defines a generic structure for parsing data
    public void parseDataAndGenerateFile(String fileDownloadType)
    {
        createHeader(fileDownloadType);
        generateFile();

    }


    //We have to write output in a excel file so this step will be same for all subclasses

    public void createHeader(String fileDownloadType)
    {
        System.out.println('Creating HEADER in EXCEL');
    }
    public void generateFile(String fileDownloadType)
    {
        System.out.println('Output generated,writing to XLX');
    }
}
public class ExcelDataParser extends FileHelper {
String fileDownloadType="";   
}

public class TemplateMethodMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileDownloadType="expired"; 
        ExcelDataParser csvDataParser=new ExcelDataParser();
        csvDataParser.parseDataAndGenerateFile(fileDownloadType);


    }

}
```

Please help me and correct me to have a good way of doing this.

Comment: what exactly is your problem ?

Comment: `createHeader` and `generateFile` must be abstract methods. So each class that extends FileHelper must implement it.

Comment: Operation is fixed and in createHeader(based on the type, i would call DB and create HEAD) and generateFile(based on the type, i would call DB and create HEAD). that is why i have only one class, but dont know whether this is the right way, if not would you please help me with..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use an abstract base class, you better should declare an abstract method `String getDownloadType()` in your abstract base class. These method must be overridden by the derived classes and the type could be fix in the derived  class. 
For example:

```
abstract public class FileHelper {

    abstract String getFileDownloadType();

    public void parseDataAndGenerateFile() {
        createHeader();
        generateFile();
    }

    public void createHeader() {
        if ("expired".equals(getFileDownloadType())) {

        } else {

        }
    }

    public void generateFile() {
        if ("expired".equals(getFileDownloadType())) {

        } else {

        }
    }
}

public class ExcelDataParser extends FileHelper {
    @Override
    String getFileDownloadType() {
        return "expired";
    }
}

public class TemplateMethodMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExcelDataParser csvDataParser = new ExcelDataParser();
        csvDataParser.parseDataAndGenerateFile();
    }
}
```

But if you don't need a class for every type, you also could make the type a variable inside a single class and passing the type to the contructor
For example:

```
public class CsvFileHelper {

    private final String fileDownloadType;

    public CsvFileHelper(String type) {
        fileDownloadType = type;
    }

    public void parseDataAndGenerateFile() {
        createHeader();
        generateFile();
    }

    public void createHeader() {
        if ("expired".equals(fileDownloadType)) {

        } else {

        }
    }

    public void generateFile() {
        if ("expired".equals(fileDownloadType)) {

        } else {

        }
    }
}

public class TemplateMethodMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CsvFileHelper csvDataParser = new CsvFileHelper("expired");
        csvDataParser.parseDataAndGenerateFile();
    }
}
```